# How to upload docker container logs from TRAVIS CI to remote machine?

Tags: docker, travis-ci, logfile

I am running unit and functional tests on Docker Containers using TRAVIS CI. My requirement is, I want to store `logs files` in a remote server/machine for future reference. I read below link 
https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/uploading-artifacts/ 
and could able to upload log files into `S3` but for `PR's` (Other than owner of the repo) this doesn't work.

Is there any way to upload Log files into a Remote Server/machine. Please let me know if there is any option to do this.